# Pass javascript json data with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have build this function:

```
function currentDate() {
    var date;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();

    // if the month length = 1 add "0" to ir
    if (currentDate.getMonth().toString().length == 1) {
        month.toString();
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    // if the day length = 1 add "0" to ir  
    if (currentDate.getDate().toString().length == 1) {
        day.toString();
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    var ISO = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    var EUR = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    return date = {
        "ISO": ISO,
        "EUR": EUR
    };
}
```

When I click on a button I want the ISO date or the EUR date to be passed into a text input. How can this be done???

Thank you..

Comment: And you just need `return { "ISO": ISO, "EUR": EUR };`. No need for `date = `, especially as you don't even use `date`.

Comment: tnx man I'll keep that in mind... the json variable will be accessed directly then

Comment: There is _no JSON here_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When defining an object the key does not need to be in quotes.

```
<input id="cdate" />
<input type="button" onclick="$('#cdate').val(currentDate().ISO)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out [this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SgguL/)

```
<button data-type="EUR">set date EUR</button>
<button data-type="ISO">set date ISO</button>
<input id="date" type="text" />
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    var d = currentDate(),
        type = $(this).data().type;
    $('#date').val(d[type]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <Script>
      // your sript goes here
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <input type="text" id="date" size="15" /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('date').value=currentDate().ISO;" value="ISO" />
    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('date').value=currentDate().EUR;" value="EUR" />
    ,...
  </body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zLc9z/)**

Or jQuery: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zLc9z/1/)**